# Attribute routing is failing for MVC/WebApi combo project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I am trying to create an ASP.NET app that is both MVC and Web Api. The default controller (HomeController) returns a view that is composed of some HTML and jQuery. I would like to use the jQuery to call the API that is part of the same project.

I have the API setup and have been testing it with Postman but I get the following error when trying to reach the endpoints in the API.

```
{
  "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:19925/api/encryption/encrypt'.",
  "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'Values' that matches the request."
}
```

I am attempting to use attribute routing so I am pretty sure that is where I am going wrong.

```
    [RoutePrefix("api/encryption")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("encrypt")]
        public IHttpActionResult EncryptText(string plainText, string keyPassPhrase)
        {
            // Method details here

            return Ok(cipherText);
        }
}
```

I have the route prefix set to `api/encryption`. I also have the method using the route `encrypt` and marked as a `HttpPost`. Below is my WebApiConfig which I think is configured properly for attribute routing.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Default MVC routing
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

By my understanding a `POST` to the following URL should reach the method ..

`http://localhost:19925/api/encryption/encrypt`

yet it isn't. I am posting the two string values to the method via Postman. I have attached a screen capture (and yes the keyPassPhrase is fake).
[image]

Here is the global.asax as requested ...

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

One other thing to note ... that when I change from GET to POST in Postman it works .. as long as I am sending the parameters along in the query string. If I send the parameters in the body I get the original error.

Comment: What is the full namespaces of the `[Route]` and `[HttpPost`] attributes you're using?

Comment: The namespace is `namespace EncryptionDemo.Controllers`. The ValuesController is the default controller generated by the ASP.NET project. I just removed the Index methods and added my own.

Comment: I asked about the full namespace of the `[Route]` and `[HttpPost]` attributes. Not the controller...

Comment: Sorry my error. [HttpPost] = `HttpPostAttribute.HttpPostAttribute()` and [Route("encrypt")] = `RouteAttribute.RouteAttribute(string template)`

Comment: That's still not the full namespace. Make sure you're using those that reside in `System.Web.Http` and not in `System.Web.Mvc`. Sadly, they share the exact same name

Comment: I apologize if I am not understanding correctly. I do have `using System.Web.Http`. Instead of `[HttpPost]` should I be using `[System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute]`

Comment: No, as long as it's actually `System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute` and `System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute`, you should be fine

Comment: Did you make sure your `WebApiConfig.Register` is actually invoked? Can you show your `Global.asax`?

Comment: Do you know how to make sure the attributes are using the proper namespace?

Comment: Hover with your mouse over the `[HttpPost]` and you'll see a tooltip with the full namespace, you can also click `F12` when your cursor is on it to see the full definition

Comment: I added the `Global.asax' as requested. I had not edited it at all.

Comment: @haim770 - I follow how to check what the namespace is for the attribute, but how do I force it to use `System.Web.Http` if it is not? Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can always use the full namespace: `System.Web.Http.HttpPostAttribute`, but at this point I already assumed you're using the correct one.

Comment: Could this be related to Web Api not being able to bind the methods with multiple parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to POST two values to an API method that accepted two parameters. This is not possible with the API (well not without some work arounds) as the API method is expecting an object rather than two different primitive types (i.e. String).

This means on the server side I needed to create a simple class that held the values I wanted to pass. For example ...

```
public class EncryptionPayload
{
    public string PlainText { get; set; }
    public string PassPhrase { get; set; }
}
```

I then modified my API method to accept a type of this class

```
    [Route("encrypt")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult EncryptText(EncryptionPayload payload)
    {
      string plainText = payload.PlainText;
      string passPhrase = payload.PassPhrase

      // Do encryption stuff here

      return Ok(cipherText);
    }
```

Then inside that controller I pulled the `Strings` I needed from the EncryptionPayload class instance. On the client side I needed to send my data as a JSON string like this ..

```
{"plainText":"this is some plain text","passPhrase":"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"}
```

After changing these things everything worked in Postman. In the end I wasn't taking into account `Model Binding`, thinking instead that an API endpoint that accepted POST could accept multiple primitive values.

This [post from Rick Strahl](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods) helped me figure it out. [This page from Microsoft](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) on Parameter Binding also explains it by saying **At most one parameter is allowed to read from the message body.**

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code. It will work :

```
[RoutePrefix("api/encryption")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("encrypt"),HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult EncryptText(string plainText, string keyPassPhrase)
        {
            // Method details here

            return Ok(cipherText);
        }
}
```

Sorry dear it was really compile time error. I edit my code. Please copy it and paste it in yourcode. Mark as answer If i Helped.

Comment: I tried it but got a compile error `The name 'HttpPost' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: Thanks for the help but I still get the same error even with the change